# Change the button's image on click with State variable as String?

Tags: string, image, button, swiftui, boolean

We can change the image with the help of a button using state variable as Boolean. But how do we achieve that using a string variable?

For Example:

If State variable is a bool:-

Image(systemName: **self**.typeClicked ? "heart.fill" : "heart.fill")

what will come in the place of  " **self**.typeClicked ? "heart.fill" : "heart.fill" " if the state variable is String?

When the typeClicked = "success" the image should change, if it is other than "success" the image should retain its previous condition.

What I have tried so far:

```
State variables:

    @State private var type: String = "success"
    
    @State private var typeClicked: Bool =  false
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = addWishlist()

MyView :

  VStack{
            HStack {
                Image("resort1")
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    if viewModel.responses?.type == "success" {
                        typeClicked.toggle()
                    } else {
                        typeClicked = false
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: self.typeClicked ? "heart.fill" : "heart.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 25))
                        .foregroundColor(self.typeClicked ? .red : Color.init(uiColor: .systemGray3))
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
```

Network class:

class addWishlist: ObservableObject {

```
@Published private(set) var records: addRecord?

@Published private(set) var responses: add?

func loadData() {
    let url = URL(string: addwishlist_URL)
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let postString = "roomid=xxxxxxxxxxx&emailid=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let todoData = data {
                let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(add.self, from: todoData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.records = decodedData.record
                    print(decodedData.record)
                    print(decodedData.type)
                }
            } else {
                print("No data")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

structs:

struct add: Codable {
var type: String
let record: addRecord
}

I want my view to be changed only with "type". which is "type": "success" in my api response.

Comment: Unrelated, but why is `responses` optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach, when you want to have `typeClicked` a String:

```
 @State private var type: String = "success"
 @State private var typeClicked = "fail"  // <-- here
 @StateObject var viewModel = addWishlist()
 
  //.....
 
     VStack{
         HStack {
             Image("resort1")
             Spacer()
             Button {
                 if viewModel.responses?.type == "success" {
                     // toggle equivalent
                     typeClicked = typeClicked == "success" ? "fail" : "success"  // <-- here
                 } else {
                     typeClicked = "fail"   // <-- here
                 }
             } label: {
                 Image(systemName: typeClicked == "success" ? "heart.fill" : "heart")  // <-- here
                     .font(.system(size: 25))
                     .foregroundColor(typeClicked == "success" ? .red : Color.init(uiColor: .systemGray3))  // <-- here
             }
         }
         .padding()
     }
```

Note, you could also just use `Image(systemName: "heart.fill")` and just play with the filling color,
`.foregroundColor(typeClicked == "success" ? .red : Color.init(uiColor: .systemGray3))`

EDIT-1:

Here is my fully working code I used to test my answer. When you tap/click on
the `heart` button, it changes color depending on the `typeClicked` String value.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var type: String = "success"
    @State private var typeClicked = "fail"  // <-- here
  // @StateObject var viewModel = addWishlist()  // commented for testing
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack {
                Image("resort1")
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    // simulated toggle, like you had it with the Bool
                    typeClicked = typeClicked == "success" ? "fail" : "success"
                    // commented for testing
//                    if viewModel.responses?.type == "success" {
                          // typeClicked = "success"   // <-- alternative to toggle
//                        typeClicked = typeClicked == "success" ? "fail" : "success"
//                    } else {
//                        typeClicked = "fail"
//                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 25))
                        .foregroundColor(typeClicked == "success" ? .red : Color.init(uiColor: .systemGray3))
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, Already tried this method but the image colour remains gray.  That isn't changing!? any other possible way?

Comment: updated my answer to have the color changing. When you click on the `Button` the heart will change color.

Comment: Your EDIT-1 working fine, but that's not working with the condition 
[/ if viewModel.responses?.type == "success" { // typeClicked = "success" // <-- alternative to toggle // typeClicked = typeClicked == "success" ? "fail" : "success" // } else { // typeClicked = "fail" // }]

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen when `viewModel.responses?.type == "success"`. Do you want the `heart` to be red or gray?  Note, my code address your question `...We can change the image with the help of a button using state variable as Boolean. But how do we achieve that using a string variable?`. My answer does that.

Comment: My view model.responses?.type is a string, that has (“type” : “success”). When api hits, my image should change to red from grey and vice versa. That colour change should only happen when "type" matches to string “success”(which is my api response)

Comment: you are saying that `viewModel.responses?.type` is the String `"type" : "success"` or
 are you saying the `viewModel.responses?.type` can be the String "success".

Comment: could you add
                    `print("--> viewModel.responses?.type: \(viewModel.responses?.type)")`
                    just before `if viewModel.responses?.type == "success" {...}` and show us
                     what it prints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252219/discussion-between-aroona-and-workingdog-support-ukraine).

Comment: no thank you, I don't do chat. Can you show the results of the print.

Comment: Edited my question, added my network class and structs..In which i'm receiving print(decodedData.record), print(decodedData.type) in my console as per my api response. The "type" is nil only in the view side.

Comment: Well, great, the "type" is nil, and my code does exactly what you want to do, 
the `heart` stay gray, because `viewModel.responses?.type` is not equal to "success".
Note that in your `loadData()` you do not set `responses` to anything, that is why it is alway nil. You should use the convention of naming your types in uppercase, such as `struct Add: Codable ....` and give them more meaningful names.

Comment: Wow! great thank you so much. Yes as you said I missed to set the responses with my decoded data. missed this one line. Now everything working fine.